# perforce client pending changelist black triangle

Tags: perforce, p4v

All of my pending changelists have turned from red to black.  What does this indicate?  I am running Rev. P4V/NTX64/2017.1/1491634

If it's related, I cannot unlock files or edit the changelists.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC the iconography for pending changelists is:

- red changelist: current workspace
- blue changelist: another workspace

I'd figure black changelist means there is no current workspace?  I don't think I've ever opened the pending changelist tab without a workspace selected (since you can't very well work on files with no workspace...)

Answer (score 2):

I found the following documentation: [P4V User Guide](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/) (See "Using P4V" > "About P4V Icons")

**Black:** Pending changelist in another workspace. *(Inferred! Read below)*

**Red:** Pending changelist with open files.

**Blue:** Pending changelist with no open files.

Frustratingly, there was no *official* documentation about black icons - but I have found that the meaning seems to correlate to "another workspace". This would make sense if you didn't have a workspace selected for all icons to show up as black.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the same issue just now, and it turned out that I had a different workspace selected (by accident) than I thought I did. This caused all the files to still show up, but with the black triangle. After switching to the correct workspace again, I could perform my changes on them as before.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it changed, but I didn't have a workspace selected.